# Python accuracy for tesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, floating-accuracy

I have run the tesseract ocr convert image file into string.

Now i have the out put

how do i compare the original PNG file and output text file whether the accuarcy is correct

```
basewidth = 2700
img = Image.open('D:OCR\\page1.png')
wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('page1_zoom.png') 
print(image_to_string(Image.open('D:\page1_zoom.png')))
```

Comment: You need to hand annotate the data.

Comment: What does it mean to "compare the original PNG file and output text file whether the accuarcy is correct"? Are you trying to validate OCR by using OCR? Generally you'd validate this kind of thing manually.

Comment: You are begging the question - to validate the OCR, you need another, even more accurate OCR - which you don't have. Which means you validate it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to check is something is accurate ?

Definitely you will need some **manual baseline/ Golden data** to compare results to. You will need your test data or at least the parameters you want to verify to.

```
Test cases could be something like: 
 1. Whole textual data 
 2. No of lines 
 3. No of Paragraphs 
 4. Position of text
```

**Tesseract vs Google ocr:**

> If you want to test tesseract accuracy with other OCR then you can try
>   google OCR that gives better results than tesseract (although it is
>   based on it)

**Tesseract training:**

```
Tesseract does provide feature of training to improve the accuracy of results.
```